# Переброска всех запросов с порта 8000 на порт 80. FastAPI

Tags: python, сервер, fastapi

У меня есть скрипт FastAPI, я запускаю его на сервере на порту 8000

```
python -m uvicorn main:app --host myhost.ru --port 8000
```

Теперь я делаю запросы к api:

```
curl myhost.ru:8000/api/method1
curl myhost.ru:8000/api/method2
curl myhost.ru:8000/api/... И тд
```

Как мне сделать переброску всех запросов с порта 8000 на порт 80?
Чтобы работало

```
curl myhost.ru/api/method
```

Comment: Можно поднять nginx на порту 80, который уже будет перенаправлять все на 8000 порт.